# $T(f(x)) = f'(x)g(x) +2f(x)$ Compute $[T]_{\beta}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $T: P_2(R) \rightarrow P_2(R) $ , $T(f(x)) = f'(x)g(x) +2f(x)$ with $g(x) = 3 +x$ Let $\beta$ be the standard ordered bases of $P_2(R)$, respectively. Compute $[T]_{\beta}$.

So $\beta = (1,x,x^2)$. I have troubles with that notation of T. I know how to compute $[T]_{\beta}$ i general and i know also how to derivate . But what exactly means for example $T(f(x)) = f'(x)$? What is in that case $T(1),T(x),T(x^2)$?

Comment: probably should rename one of your $T$'s something else

Answer (score 1):

From $$T(f(x)) = f'(x)g(x) +2f(x)$$ and $$ g(x)=3+x $$ we can compute $T(1),T(x),T(x^2)$.

$T(1)=2$ because for $f(x)=1$ the derivative $f'(x)=0$

$T(x)= g(x)+2f(x)= 3+x+2x =3+3x$

$T(x^2)=2xg(x)+2x^2 = 6x+4x^2$

Now you can find the matrix $ [T]_{\beta}$ by noticing that $T(1)=1(1)+0(x)+0(x^2)$ and $T(x)=3(1)+3(x)+0(x^2)$ and $T(x^2)=0(1)+6(x)+4(x^2).$

The case of $T(f(x))=f'(x)$ is much easier to compute, you just differentiate $f(x)$ to get $T(f(x)).

Comment: ah this will be confusing, as op used $T$ to mean two different things

Comment: We can still make sense of the question regardless of two different cases of T

Comment: well $T(1)$ is different depending on which one you chose

Comment: Yes, it is. We need to stay consistent and not jump from one to the other.

Answer (score 0):

$T(f(x))=f'(x)$ means $T$ maps a function to its derivative. This is indeed a linear map,
since differentiation is linear. So to answer your question, 
$$
T(1)=\frac{d}{dx}(1)=0\\
T(x)=\frac{d}{dx}(x)=1\\
T(x^2)=\frac{d}{dx}(x^2)=2x
$$

Your map is a bit different, but with this cleared up I hope you will be able to proceed.